# How to change get_custom_logo() url?

Tags: theme-development, logo

I need to change default WordPress `get_custom_logo()` generated url because I need to link to the main multi-site site instead of single site. Is there any filter to change this function?

Answer (score 5):

I solved using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo',  'custom_logo_url' );
function custom_logo_url ( $html ) {

$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$url = network_site_url();
$html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( $url  ),
        wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, array(
            'class'    => 'custom-logo',
        ) )
    );
return $html;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
function update_logo_url( $html ) {
    $site_url = get_site_url();

    return str_replace( $site_url, esc_url( 'https://your.url' ), $html );
}

add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'update_logo_url' );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  If at all possible, try to include a bit of information explaining why your answer works and what's happening in the code.