# Changing custom logo link

Tags: php, functions, custom-header, logo

I am trying to change my custom logo url on wordpress to go to a different website. I have tried many different ways to do this with php and child themes but every time I try something it just breaks the site.

I have created a child theme and copied my header.php file.

Here is the section from the header.php file that talks about the custom logo:

```
            <div class="logo">
                <?php if( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) : ?>
                <figure class="logo-image">
                    <?php flash_the_custom_logo(); ?>
                    <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'flash_transparent_logo', '') != '') : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                        <img class="transparent-logo" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'flash_transparent_logo', '' ) ); ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </figure>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I am pretty new to php so I'm not super great at coding it but here are the things I have attempted with trying to change my logo url:

I believe this line needs to be changed from the code above:

```
   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

So I have tried these: (I am just using google for example purposes)

```
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url(https://www.google.com/); ?>">

  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
```

I saw from a thread a year ago that a filter could be an option like this one from the thread: [How to change get_custom_logo() url?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232174/how-to-change-get-custom-logo-url) . However, I do not know where in there to put my new url.

```
add_filter( 'get_custom_logo',  'custom_logo_url' );
function custom_logo_url ( $html ) {

$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$url = network_site_url();
$html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" 
itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
    esc_url( $url  ),
    wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, array(
        'class'    => 'custom-logo',
    ) )
);
return $html;    
}
```

If someone could help me figure this problem out I would really appreciate it. I have tried researching it and coding it myself but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your url in the `href` attribute of the link - like this (I used http://example.com):

```
            <?php if( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) : ?>
            <figure class="logo-image">
                <?php flash_the_custom_logo(); ?>
                <?php if( get_theme_mod( 'flash_transparent_logo', '') != '') : ?>
                <a href="http://example.com">
                    <img class="transparent-logo" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'flash_transparent_logo', '' ) ); ?>" />
                </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </figure>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help me with my question I really appreciate it. However, when I put this code in and went to click on my logo it turned my whole website white. You can go to my website but it's just a white screen now. I'll have to delete out the code to fix it again but do you know of another solution?

Comment: The code above is perfectly fine, it does not cause any errors. The "white screen of death" is most likely caused by a PHP syntax error elsewhere in your file. Just put your full code (for that file) on pastebin and I'll take a look.

Comment: Here is the Pastbin url: https://pastebin.com/gD0hXXVS   Thank you for taking a look at it I really appreciate it. @Mihai Papuc

Comment: The code has no syntax error. Could you also put the working code in pastebin? I will compare the two. But do make sure these are the only changes between the working version and the one that throws you the error.